# Paypal button integration passing session variables

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, integration, payment-gateway

Hello guys I am developing a web store where users are already registered it must track both users the one that is selling the item and the one that is buying the item also some instructions the buyer might to express to the seller.

I have not performed this kind of tasks before have been reviewing the Paypal developer Api however have not found the exact functionality I need right now.

i need to pass session variables from my app into the paypal mechanism.

Please let me know how to integrate a button for buying an item and then store the details about the transaction in my db cause need to know the userid of the users within my app.

Thanks a lot.-

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use the Express Checkout API or simple PayPal Standard + IPN

If you use Express Checkout, then you don't need to send any session variable to PayPal as the session is not closed and the last step of the transaction (DoExpressCheckoutPayment) occurs in your website. But, if you really want to send some custom data to PayPal you can do it by sending "PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM" inside the SetExpressCheckout call.

If you use PayPal Standard + IPN. You can pass to PayPal the variable called "custom" (*Pass-through variable for your own tracking purposes, which buyers do not see*) and retrieve it back in the IPN.